# For loop does not index properly - placing results in a matrix from for loop

Tags: r

So I'm trying to do 10 different bootstrap simulations, with sample sizes 10,20,...,100. So I've created a vector containing these sample sizes and then iterate over them using a for loop as shown below.

The while loop just computes the mean of the bootstrap sample 1800 times, and stores all these values in the vector K. This means I should get 10 different of these vectors K and finally for every j, i want to place each K in one column in the matrix L.

The problem is that I get the matrix L, but all the columns are identical. There is something wrong with the loop and I can't figure out what it is.

Any input is appreciated. Here is my code:

```
N = 1800
i = 0
K = vector("numeric", 1800L)
L = matrix(nrow = 1800, ncol = 10)
ListValues = c(10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100)

for (j in 1:10){
  while (i <= N){
    x = sample(Data, ListValues[j])
    K[i] = mean(x)
    i = i + 1
  }
  L[,j] = K
}
print(L)
```

Result:

```
> print(L)
            [,1]     [,2]     [,3]     [,4]     [,5]     [,6]     [,7]     [,8]     [,9]    [,10]
   [1,] 3.669182 3.669182 3.669182 3.669182 3.669182 3.669182 3.669182 3.669182 3.669182 3.669182
   [2,] 3.764834 3.764834 3.764834 3.764834 3.764834 3.764834 3.764834 3.764834 3.764834 3.764834
   [3,] 4.324697 4.324697 4.324697 4.324697 4.324697 4.324697 4.324697 4.324697 4.324697 4.324697
   [4,] 4.473386 4.473386 4.473386 4.473386 4.473386 4.473386 4.473386 4.473386 4.473386 4.473386
```

Comment: In `R` indexing begins with 1 (not with 0). Should the initialization `i=1` be placed before the while-loop ?

Answer (score 3):

Here is a shorter version:

```
N <- 1800L
L <- matrix(nrow = N, ncol = 10)
ListValues <- c(10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100)
for (j in 1:10) L[,j] <- replicate(N, mean(sample(Data, ListValues[j])))
```

or even shorter (but not faster):

```
N <- 1800L
ListValues <- c(10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100)
L <- sapply(1:10, function(j) replicate(N, mean(sample(Data, ListValues[j]))))
```

Comment: `replicate` can return matrices, no need for loops or `sapply` at all.

Comment: @KonradRudolph Normally I would do `matrix(replicate(...), ...)`, but in this case each column of the desired matrix has its own parametrization. How would you do with only one call of `replicate() `?

Comment: Right, you can’t. I was thinking you could sample a matrix rather than a vector, use `colMeans` rather than `mean` and surround the whole with `replicate`. But `sample` isn’t vectorised on `size` so that won’t work. And you can’t invert the logic either because then you’d have to sample `size` * 10 with replacement, which isn’t the same as sampling `size` without replacement ten times.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
N = 1800
i = 0
K = vector("numeric", 1800L)
L = matrix(nrow = 1800, ncol = 10)
ListValues = c(10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100)

for (j in 1:10){
  i = 0
  while (i <= N){
    x = sample(Data, ListValues[j])
    K[i] = mean(x)
    i = i + 1
  }
  L[,j] = K
}
print(L)
```

Comment: Wow… it worked. How come the i=0 was the issue? I thought i=0 only needed to be initiated once before the loops :S I'd give you an upvote but my reputation is low.

Comment: Everytime you pass through a j, and finish a complete while i<=N cycle, the i ends up being i = 1800, so it never enters the while again, unless you initialize it

Comment: @karen For `i=0` the assignment `K[i] = mean(x)` has no effect! Try `K <- numeric(5);
K[0] <- 42;
K`

Comment: i does has an effect, because everytime we compute the mean with a different size sample although the Data is the same, this is why we use j to roll through listvalues

Comment: what jogo meant is, in [tag:R], first index is `1` not `0` so `K[0]` doesn't define any element of K, hence the value of the specific `mean(x)` will be lost (not store anywhere).

Comment: I don't see the benefit of a `while` loop with initialization and updating of `i` over a `for` loop (`for(i in 1:N){...}`)?